# Visual Studio Azure Subscription Login Error

Tags: visual-studio, authentication, azure, subscription

I have been using VS for working on a lot of my Azure hosted websites. Just recently I tried to open VS and open the website and was prompted to sign in.

Upon signing in I received this error:

> An error occurred during the sign in process:
>   authentication_ui_failed: The browser based authentication dialog
>   failed to complete for an unknown reason

I have researched this issue, but have very limited results that don't pertain to my issue.

I have tried to reset IE back to it's original settings and tried adding another role onto my subscription but nothing seems to do anything different.